# Search not returning desired results

Tags: product, product-attribute, search, catalogsearch, search-criteria

I'm having problems with the search in my magento webshop. I have different products in my webshop. An example of the name of a product is like this:

> BODYSOL KIDS DOUCHE 2IN1 WATERMELOEN 250ML

This is my **configuration of my catalog search**:

[image]

This are my **case scenarios**:

1. **Search type: "Like"**

   - When I search for **"BODYSOL KIDS"** I'm getting 495 products back.
   - When I search for **"BODYSOL KIDS DOUCHE 2IN1 WATERMELOEN 250ML"** I'm getting 876 products back.
2. **Search type: "Fulltext"**

   - When I search for **"BODYSOL KIDS"** I'm getting 494 products back.
   - When I search for **"BODYSOL KIDS DOUCHE 2IN1 WATERMELOEN 250ML"** I'm getting 832 products back.
3. **Search type: "Combine (Like and Fulltext)”"**

   - When I search for **"BODYSOL KIDS"** I'm getting 495 products back.
   - When I search for **"BODYSOL KIDS DOUCHE 2IN1 WATERMELOEN 250ML"** I'm getting 876 products back.

**PROBLEM:**

When I look for the full string of the product I'm getting to many products back ... . How is this possible? ...

Answer (score 1):

When we search for word "BODYSOL KIDS DOUCHE 2IN1 WATERMELOEN 250ML"

It split word in array ("BODYSOL", "KIDS", "DOUCHE", "2IN1", "WATERMELOEN", "250ML")

By default our product description and short description attribute "Use in Quick Search" is set to yes

So when you trying it will search split string in all product in attribute "Product Name", "Product Short Description" and "Product Description".

So if you need exact search go to "Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes"

Edit Description and Short Description Set "Use in Quick Search" , "Use in Advanced Search" to "No".

hope this is helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Did you check which attributes you have set for "Use in Quick Search" in every attribute's settings in backend?

The quick search queries with like on all attribute you set.